# Issue updating Parse object on local datastore

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm building an app where user tags their opinion about books. I have this tag object saving to Parse local datastore before it's saved to network. I want to delete existing tag PFObject and then save the updated object instead so there is only one row with the dictionary of data.

I'm not sure what my issue is, any feedback from you is greatly appreciated!!

```
         let tag = PFObject(className: "UserTags")

         tag.unpinInBackgroundWithName(bookObjectID, block: { (success, error) -> Void in

            if success {

               // sets a pointer to the user in the tag
               tag["user"] = self.user

               // sets pointer to candidate
               tag["book"] = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"Books", objectId:self.bookObjectID)

               tag["data"] = self.tagsForBookDict

               tag["bookObjectID"] = self.bookObjectID

               // setting meta dictionary with user values from earlier
               tag["meta"] = ["gender":gender, "age":age, "party":party, "state":state]

               PFObject.pinAllInBackground([tag], withName: self.bookObjectID, block: { (success, error) -> Void in

                  print(tag)

               })
            }
         })
      }
   }
```

Comment: First of all, you should post the error you get if you want us to help. Second, you should probably save `tag` before you pin it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's the thing, there is no error, it gets in that success block like it successfully unpinned it. I do want to pin this data first and only save to network at a certain point to limit parse network traffic.